# Scroll bar showing on popup

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the scroll option when a pop up is visible on the site. For some reason the scroll bar still shows when the pop up is there.

```
/******* Lock Scroll When Popup shows **********/
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // document is loaded and DOM is ready
  var light = $("#light").css("display");
  if(light == "block")    // if value of id 'light' is display:block
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
  else
    $('body').css('overflow','scroll');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code you used worked (and still works) in many browsers, but not on iPad for example. You would have to do following, but that may cause other errors (believe me, you may have nightmares with scrolled content in overflow area):

```
html, body{
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important; /* not sure about this line is required now */
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```